# UINavigationBar set tintcolor tested in iOS7 not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, tintcolor

I have an app which have a `UINavigationBar` and I have set the tint color to black like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];`
```

I have tested it in IOS 6 and it's black. However, it appears as the default navigation bar when I tried the same app in iOS 7.

As the title says, is it not working?

Comment: same problem here. everything else works fine

Comment: //for ios6
    [Helper navController].navigationBar.tintColor = [Helper getThemeColorWithTransparent:NO];

    //for ios7, not working
    if ([[Helper navController].navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
        [[Helper navController].navigationBar performSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:) withObject:[Helper getThemeColorWithTransparent:NO]];
    }
I tried the above, but still not working. This is weird. It should be fine even on iOS7 if the base sdk is 6

Comment: the beta 2 update fixed this issue.

Comment: if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor =  [self backgoundColorForCurrentCompany];
 }

Comment: @veereef : try this......self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 22):

You need to set the barTintColor property.

> You can specify a custom tint color for the navigation bar background using the Tint (barTintColor) field. The default background tint color is white.

From iOS7 docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UINavigationBar-SW1

Comment: but the thing is, if ur base sdk is 6.0, the color should be correct. weird

Comment: this is not working for me in iOS7 but the original code from the question did work...

Answer (score 17):

Fernando's and sanjana's answers have the key, but I'll just add something to make it clearer and more obvious.

The navigation bar has two properties

- tintColor
- barTintColor

It's a bit misleading when you don't think in iOS 7 terms.

`tintColor` changes the color of the buttons on your navigation bar.
To change the background color, you need to set the property `barTintColor`.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This code snippet will give you a white navigation bar with green buttons.

Comment: tintColor can apply to more than just buttons on your navigation bar. UIImageView's that contain images with transparent pixels can be 'tinted' by their superview's tint property. So if I have a table view cell with tintColor = [UIColor blueColor], my image will appear blue when added to the cell's content view.

Answer (score 8):

I used following code to change tint color of navigation bar in iOS7,I added this in app delegate "applicationDidFinishLaunch" method and its work fine for me :

```
/* ios 7 Change */
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x4B678B)];
        NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                               [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                               shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                               [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
        // self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        //[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    }
```

Comment: THIS LINE was magic for me.  All I needed in iOS7.1 the nav colour seemed to break. [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x4B678B)];

Answer (score 4):

Following code is working for me :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, but solved it via storyboard file.

Try the following.

1. Open your .storyboard file.
2. Select the scene with navigation controller
3. Select Navigation Bar item into Navigation Controller scene
   [image]
4. Open the Utilities tab on the right side of XCode
5. Open Attributes Inspector
6. In "Navigation Bar" group there will be Bar Tint dropdown list. You can choose any color for a tint.
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

```
    [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if ([[UINavigationBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
        [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor   = [UIColor redColor];
    }
```

//OR

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor    = [UIColor redColor];
    }
```