# No tint color for a navigationBar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have an extension on `UINavigationController` that sets the `navigationBar.tintColor` and makes it transparent:

```
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

But What I want to have is to have a transparent navigation bar, with visible items that have no tint color at all. I add a right navigation bar item that has a coloured background image:

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "avatar")!,
                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, 
                                  target: self,     
                                  action: #selector(self.rightNavBarItemAction))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

Instead of having an image as the background of the button, I get a white placeholder. Using `UIColor.clearColor()` makes the button transparent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041778/uinavigationbar-set-tintcolor-tested-in-ios7-not-working try this link,by default background tint color is white.

Comment: @ManishSingh it's blue by default

Comment: Try setting the barTintColor to clearColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

[image]

***Hope it work for you. Thanks***